# Magento 2 - How to remove unused javascript from product page

Tags: magento2

Currently magento 2 product page too slower in mobile device. Magento and theme make combined js file more than 1 MB. then we need to include some google analytics js, facebook pixel etc.

All these js making page slower because parsing time is too high. As per new google webmaster speed experimental, everyone need to optimize website.

Can anyone help to remove or reduce js size on product page?

Comment: pls accept it as answer if this helped you

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 take care of speed, once you changes your website to `Production mode`.
It `merges/minifies all the js` running on website by `default`, if you have changed anything yet, then while being in `Developer mode` change `minify js to YES`, then turn into `Production mode` again.

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production (for changing in production)
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer (for changing in developer)
```

Don't forget to run upgrade, compile and static content later.

Comment: Everything is done but does not help. After all things, compress js file size is 4 MB which gzip compression to 1 MB.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into something like cloudflare

Activate Auto Minify in their Cloudflare settings. Auto Minify will remove all unnecessary characters from HTML, JavaScript, and CSS files. Once Cloudflare returns a cache HIT for the file it will be returned to browsers in minified form

This is the easiest method.

Otherwise you will have to invest time and money having a developer look at your assets and possibly install a few extensions

Comment: All setting applied but cloudfare just do cache and minify. It does not remove unused js.

Answer (score 0):

After lots of debugging, i found that we should disable plugin in app/etc/config.php which are not in use in current application. it helps to remove unused js.

Another way to exclude js in app/design/frontend/{vendor}/{theme}/etc/view.xml.